# Semigroup without a weak basis

Tags: model-theory, semigroups

Let $\mathfrak{S}=(S,*)$ be a semigroup and $X\subseteq S$. Consider the functional closure $\overline{X}$, i.e. minimal set containing $X$ and closed under $*$. Let's say that $X$ is a weak basis (in contrast with the basis that is defined for a stronger concept of the algebraic closure) if $\overline{X}=S$ and $\forall(x\in X):x\notin \overline{X-\{x\}}$. One may prove that finite semigroups, free monoids and groups contain weak bases. Does it hold for all semigroups? If not, are there some counterexamples?

Comment: I'm puzzled by your claim that groups have bases.  What would be a basis for $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, for instance?

Comment: @EricWofsey I've considered the following construction. Let's order the universe $A$ of a group with some ordinal $\alpha$. Then consider the sets $S_0=\{a_0\}$, $S_{i+1}=S_i\cup\{a_{i+1}\}$ if this set is independent, or $S_i$ otherwise. The same is for $S_\lambda$ which is $\cup_{i<\lambda}S_i\cup\{a_{i+1}\}$, or $\cup_{i<\lambda}S_i$. Then the weak basis is $\cup_{i<\alpha}S_i$. Though, I could make a mistake in the proof.

Comment: The problem is that $S_i\cup\{a_{i+1}\}$ could fail to be independent because $a_{i+1}$ generates an element of $S_i$, rather than because $a_{i+1}$ is generated by $S_i$.  So, if you take $S_{i+1}=S_i$, that may not generate $a_{i+1}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey oh, it makes sense. I thought I could express $a_{i+1}$ with inverses if $S_i\cup\{a_{i+1}\}$ is not independent :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was shown in the comments, the assertion actually isn't true for groups and the counterexample is $(\mathbb{Q},+)$. Indeed, assume $a,b$ are elements of the basis $X$ and $a<b$. Suppose $a=x/z$ and $b=y/z$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $z>0$. We can write $1/z=x_1+...+x_n$ where $x_1,...,x_n\in X-\{b\}$. Then $a+(y-x)(x_1+...+x_n)=b$ that gives us a contradiction with the independence of $X$. Thus, $X$ contains just one element $q$. We have $q\neq0$ and thus $0\notin\overline{X}$.